# Google Script - Simple function not doing anything

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I made a function nearly identical to this and it worked great.  This one tells me it is running but nothing actually happens in my inbox.  I get no errors, either.

(This is my first day working with Google scripting so I'm sure it's a rookie mistake.)

```
function autoArchiveOldInboxItems() {
  var search_term = "label:inbox older_than:30d";

  while(GmailApp.search(search_term).length > 0){
    var threads = GmailApp.search(search_term,0,100);

    GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads);
  }

}
```

I tried searching "in:inbox" as well as "label:inbox".

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: search my inbox for messages older than 30 days, mark them read, and move them to archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this made it happy:

```
function kickOff(){
  autoArchiveOldInboxItems();
}
function autoArchiveOldInboxItems() {
  var search_term = "label:inbox older_than:30d";

  while(GmailApp.search(search_term).length > 0){
    var threads = GmailApp.search(search_term,0,100);

    GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads);
  }

}
```

Then, I call the kickoff function and it runs.  Strangely, when I did it before, I was in the editor and chose to run that function and it kept doing nothing.  Possible bug?  Or maybe it's just me.

You should see my inbox now.  :)